# Twitter background share on timeline

Tags: twitter, share

Facebook API allows applications to post feeds on user's timelime in case when user allowed this application to do it. So it give me opportunity to post feeds from the website to user's timeline on facebook without asking him again (in background).

Does twitter has something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The difference between facebook and twitter background share is:

1) FACEBOOK share requires application secret token, application ID and user ID. Using application secret token and application ID you can get app token. By calling API function you can post feed to user's timeline using his/her UID

```
$facebook->api('/USER_ID/feed', 'post', "YOUR MESSAGE" );
```

2) TWITTER share. You can't post tweet on user's page by his ID. To initialize connection you have to know:

-TWITTER CONSUMER TOKEN

-TWITTER CONSUMER SECRET

-USER TOKEN

-USER SECRET TOKEN

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($TWITTER_CONSUMER_TOKEN, $TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, $userToken, $userSecret);
        $result = $connection->oAuthRequest('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json', "POST", array('status' => "YOU TEXT",'media[]'  => file_get_contents("/images/your_image")));
```

My problem was that I didn't know how to post tweet to user's page by user id. Now I know - it is impossible